# searching values in string which is variable

Tags: python

Imagine that you have 100 strings with random digits, something like that:

```
str1="123"
str2="456"
str3="287"
strN="..."
```

I would like to display exactly which string contains digit "2".

For example output will be:

```
"Digit 2 is in str1 str3"
```

For str range = 4:

```
    str1 = "123"
    str2 = "456"
    str3 = "728"
    start = 0

    list = []
    while start < 4:
        b = "str%d" %start
        list.append(b)
        start+=1

    # List is ['str0', 'str1', 'str2', 'str3']

    for i in list:
        if "2" in i:
            print i
```

I would like to know how to assign element from the list, for example `"str1"` as a variable `str1`with contents `"123"`.

Comment: Where/how are you getting the different `str1` variables.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question well but I would like to say that never use `list` as name of the variable/object. `list()` and `list` is data type in python.

Comment: Please don't put stuff like `[solved]` in the title. If an answer helped you, click on the outline of the check mark (you'll find it underneath the down arrow image on the right of the question) to accept it, that will close this question automatically.

Answer (score 2):

### Exact answer, but **bad** conception:

```
search_value = '2'

str1 = "123"
str2 = "456"
str3 = "728"
start = 1

list = []
while start < 4:
    b = "str%d" % start
    list.append(b)
    start += 1

for value_name in list:
    if search_value in eval(value_name):
        print "{0} is in {1}".format(search_value, value_name)
```

Output:

```
2 is in str1
2 is in str3
```

It is used [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) here. In most cases it shouldn't be used, because it is dangerous. Also, if you need to access to variable by its name, then it is better to change code strategy.

Also, `list` is not a good name for variable, as [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is a builtin python function.

So, you better put you strings inside a dict and change some variable names.

### Another answer, **good** conseption:

```
strings = {
    "str1": "123",
    "str2": "456",
    "str3": "728",
}
search_value = '2'

for s_name in sorted(strings):
    if search_value in strings[s_name]:
        print "{0} is in {1}".format(search_value, s_name)
```

As you can see, it is more compact and readable. Output will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be this:

```
data = {'str1': str1, 'str2': str2, 'str3': str3}
dict = {key: value for (key, value) in data.iteritems() if '2' in value}
```

Then you have in list your strn variables with their proper content.

You can access a variable by name with

```
globals()['str1'] <==> globals()[dict.keys()[0]]
```